# Getting Spring Data MongoDB to recreate indexes

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'd like to be able to purge the database of all data between Integration test executions. My first thought was to use an `org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestExecutionListener`
registered using the `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation to perform the necessary cleanup between tests.

In the `afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext)` method I tried getting the database from the test context and using the `com.mongodb.DB.drop()` method. This worked ok, apart from the fact that it also destroys the indexes that were automatically created by Spring Data when it first bound my managed `@Document` objects.

For now I have fixed this by resorting to iterating through the collection names and calling remove as follows:

```
for (String collectionName : database.getCollectionNames()) {
        if (collectionIsNotASystemCollection(collectionName)
            database.getCollection(collectionName).remove(new BasicDBObject());

    }
```

This works and achieves the desired result - but it'd be nice if there was a way I could simply drop the database and just ask Spring Data to "rebind" and perform the same initialisation that it did when it started up to create all of the necessary indexes. That feels a bit cleaner and safer...

I tried playing around with the `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext` but haven't yet managed to work out if there is a way to do what I want.

Can anyone offer any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

See [this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-345) for an explanation why it currently works as it works and why working around this issue creates more problems than it solves.

Supposed you're working with Hibernate and then trigger a call to delete the database, would you even dream to assume that the tables and all indexes reappear magically? If you drop a MongoDB database/collection you remove all metadata associated with it. Thus, you need to set it up the way you'd like it to work.

P.S.: I am not sure we did ourselves a favor to add automatic indexing support as this of course triggers the expectations that you now have :). Feel free to comment on the ticket if you have suggestions how this could be achieved without the downsides I outlined in my initial comment.